# What other <tag> can be use to fire AJAX other than <button>?

Tags: html, css

I have a menu below:

```html
<ul class="r1">
  <li class="lb"><button class="bu" value="orange">Orange</button></li>
  <li class="lb"><button class="bu" value="apple">Apple</button></li>
</ul>
```

Instead of link, I add EventListener script:

```html
<script>
var bs = document.getElementsByClassName("bu");
for(var i =0; i< bs.length; i++){
bs[i].addEventListener('click', function(){ sFunction(this.value);});
}
</script>
```

When clicked it will call the ajax function below:

```html
function sFunction(value) {
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","some.php?q="+value,true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {document.getElementById("ajax").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;}}}
```

This code is working nicely. I believe it is because 'button' support the VALUE attribute which 'li' doesn't.

Now, if I don't want to use 'button', is there any other tag/element I can use to replace 'button'?

My logic is that I don't want use button to fire ajax in my menu because the button will appear on the list menu.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery?

Comment: I prefer vanila...cos it is tasteless.

Comment: You can use any element to fire ajax. Click event can happen on any element

Comment: List-item tags (`li`) do support the `value` attribute, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes

Comment: Only Number....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be any element, like `div, span` etc,, but the only thing that you need to be aware is where will you have your value saved.

If it was `button` you had it in `value` tag, and if you for example use `div` we can have it in custom tag like this,,

```js
var bs = document.getElementsByClassName("bu");
for (var i = 0; i < bs.length; i++) {
  bs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    sFunction(this.getAttribute('data-value'));
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="bu" data-value="42">Value</div>
```

So note that instead to pass `this.value` to your ajax function, we only changed that to

```
sFunction( this.getAttribute('data-value') );
```

Hope that helps you

Comment: you can use inline onclick and put variable inside it in button or div or span ..etc